# Repeatedly multiplying a number by itself - what explains the period of final digits?

Tags: number-theory

Looking at powers of 2:

$$2$$
$$4$$
$$8$$
$$16$$
$$32$$ 
$$ ... $$

There is a repetition of the rightmost digit: $\{2, 4, 8, 6\}$, and so this has a period of 4.

If I were to look at the two right most digits, then the pattern (starting at $2^4$) is $\{ 16, 32, 64, 28, 56, 12, 24, 48, 96, 92, 84, 68, 36, 72, 44, 88, 76, 52, 04, 08 \}$ with a period of 20.

I wrote a short program to find this period for some small values. I start with a number, $n$, then multiply the current value times $n$ each iteration. At each step I prune it down to $d$ digits long. I take the first value that is $d$ digits long and iterate until I come across that value again. I came up with following results:

```
      digits 
  n   | 1 |  2 |   3 |   4 |    5 |     6
      --------------------------------------
   2  | 4 | 20 | 100 | 500 | 2500 | 12500
   3  | 4 | 20 | 100 | 500 | 5000 | 50000
   4  | 2 | 10 |  50 | 250 | 1250 |  6250
   5  | 1 |  1 |   2 |   4 |    8 |    16
   6  | 1 |  5 |  25 | 125 |  625 |  3125
   7  | 4 |  4 |  20 | 100 |  500 |  5000
   8  | 4 | 20 | 100 | 500 | 2500 | 12500
   9  | 2 | 10 |  50 | 250 | 2500 | 25000
   10 | x |  x |   x |   x |    x |     x
   11 | x | 10 |  50 | 500 | 5000 | 50000
   12 | x | 20 | 100 | 500 | 2500 | 12500
   13 | x | 20 | 100 | 500 | 5000 | 50000
   14 | x |  x |   x |   x |    x |     x
   15 | x |  x |   x |   x |    x |     x
   16 | x |  5 |  25 | 125 |  625 |  3125
   17 | x | 20 | 100 | 500 | 2500 | 12500
   18 | x |  x |   x |   x |    x |     x
   19 | x | 10 |  50 | 500 | 5000 | 50000

   Table of repeated digit periods
```

These seem like nice friendly numbers, and there seems to be a certain kind of ordered progression as the number of digits increases. Is there a closed formula for determining this period without iterating through all the values?

Comment: Do you know anything about "groups"?

Comment: The final digit is the congruence class mod 10.

Comment: [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Carmichael.27s_theorem)  might be of interest

Comment: We have $$x^{4k+m}\equiv x^m\mod 10$$ for positive integers $x,k,m$

Comment: @Randall ok, but what happened to the other 6 for $2^x$? ("*There are exactly n distinct congruence classes modulo n*") And what happened to the other 9 for $6^x \pmod {10} $?

Comment: Thanks @Peter but where does the $4$ come from? And what about $x^m \pmod {10^n}$ for some positive integer n>1?

Comment: @Burnsba  there's an entire algebra of congruence classes and some associated number theory that explains this.  Peter supplied the main result.

Comment: @Burnsba This is a property of the Carmichaelfunction (See : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) . We have $\lambda(10)=4$, therefore the $4$, we also have $\phi(10)=4$, where $\phi(n)$ is the totient-function, but we do not always have $\phi(n)=\lambda(n)$

Comment: In general, we have the following : If the greatest exponent appearing in the prime factorization of a number $N$ is $k$, then, we have $$x^{\lambda(N)\cdot m+n}\equiv x^n\mod N$$ for all $x,m$ and $n\ge k$